# Anet A8 - hot end temperature still same

Tags: printer-building, hotend, anet-a8

I've recently purchased Anet A8. First print went well, but now, the hot end temperature stays at ~230 °C. When I touch it, it is still cold. I tried the thermistor, and it correctly changes resistance when I blow on it (from 100 kΩ to ~70 kΩ). The voltage in connector is about 300 mV.

Does anybody know what could be wrong?

Comment: Have you tried swapping the bed and extruder thermistors at the board?

Comment: I tried it. I fixed the problem, see my answer.

Comment: Apologies for the previously botched edit. Poor eyesight :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, I had a bad resistor on my board. R41 had only 2.2 kΩ instead of 4.7. I replaced it and everything works now.

Comment: Just out of interest, how did you know that the value of R41 was incorrect, and what the correct value should be? Did you deduce it from looking at a schematic, or comparing like components or by calculation? Or was it just a faulty resistor, that was the incorrect resistance when measured with a DMM? Was the incorrect part caused by a manufacturing or design error?

Comment: I measured it with Ohmmeter and compared the result against value written on it. I really don't know how resistor may become 'bad'. Shortening maybe?

Comment: It could have been badly soldered and over heated when the board was made; damaged in the fabrication process of the resistor itself, or; just got old? :-) **Note** that care should be taken when measuring components when on the board, rather than in isolation, as other components in parallel can change the actual reading.